# How to deploy a React JS build folder to Heroku Server from Azure release pipelines

Tags: heroku, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, heroku-ci

I am actually developing a React js application and pushing it to Azure Github (dev.azure). To automate the builds, I created pipelines and to release the build I created a release pipeline. I want to host this application on heroku app server. I used Heroku release tools in azure pipelines and the release is being sent. But in heroku activity it says

"App not compatible with buildpack:" and if i use Node js buildpack, it says package.json is not found.

I understand that its expecting my source code but not the end build folder.

But is there anyway to publish only the build folder and it directly runs on heroku server without having to deploy my code into heroku.

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below answer? Did it answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

It is said in the [heroku document](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs#overview):

> Heroku Node.js support will only be applied when the application has a package.json file in the root directory.

I am afraid you cannot push only the build folder into heroku. As it is said in the document a build of the source application will be initiated, when Heroku platform receives the application source.  See document [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/how-heroku-works#building-applications).

And then, the source code for your application, together with the fetched dependencies and output of the build phase such as generated assets or compiled code, as well as the language and framework, are assembled into a slug. The slug will be distributed to a dyno for execution. See [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler).